# Raspberry Pi: How to connect global_en with gnd on a 5v signal?

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi, reset

On a Raspberry Pi 4, you can perform a hard reset by pulling the global_en pin to low.

I want to control this reset by using an external 5v signal. When the signal is high, the reset is performed.

I know this could be easily done by using a 5v relay. However, I am not happy with this solution because the switching noise of a relay is too loud for my application.

My question is if there is any other simple solution without using a relay.

Comment: Single MOSFET pulling the signal to ground. There are many similar questions here

Comment: There are so many different mosfets. Which one should I use?

Comment: use one that will operate with 5V,  eg: 2N7000

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is simple solutions. For example, these include a transistor or logic gate can be used to pull the pin to ground when it gets 5V signal.